# Content is not retrieved from file

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, file, file-management

I've got this wired problem, I cannot get the content from the file and initiate my NSMutableArray with it.

Here's my code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"Does file exist?: %i", [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/length.txt", documentsDirectory]]);

NSMutableArray *tempArr;

tempArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/length.txt", documentsDirectory]];
```

When trying this, initWithContentsOfFile returns (null). The row checking if the file exist prints '1' to the console.

This is the code I'm using to save the data:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
[length.text writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/length.txt", documentsDirectory] atomically:NO];
```

I'm using more or less exactly the same code in a different program without problems.

Really need some help here, perhaps I'm just blind for the moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for NSArray's `initWithContentsOfFile:` method say:

> **Return Value** An array initialized to contain the contents of the file
>   specified by aPath or nil if the file
>   can’t be opened or the contents of the
>   file can’t be parsed into an array.
>   The returned object might be different
>   than the original receiver.

You don't include the declaration of `length` in your code snippet, but I'm guessing that `length.text` returns an NSString object, not an NSArray. So you'd need to read that back from a file using `initWithContentsOfFile:` from NSString, not NSArray.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't thinking about the format of the files, they are very different of course. In my other program from which I copied the code, I am both writing and reading using arrays.

Comment: Glad it helped! Sometimes all it takes is a fresh pair of eyes on your code. :)

Answer (score 2):

When you try to create an array from the contents of a file, [the file *must* be in plist format](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-CBHBDFEE), and the outer-most plist element must be `<array>`.  If it doesn't have that format, initialization will fail and your array will be `nil`.

You're creating the file by writing an `NSString` to a file, which means you should probably be reading it in to an `NSString`, not an `NSArray`.